# Map function code as filter replicator on CouchDB

Tags: javascript, android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I am using CouchDB with CouchBase Lite on Android. I would like to replicate the DB on my device, for that I would like to use [the filtered replication](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication) .

I have wrote and script that works perfectly when I run it on [Futon](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/futon.html) and all the documents with the requeriments I wrote are showed.

My problem is that if I use the code as filter It does not work on my mobile device and I dont get documents with the requeriments that I need.

This is the function that works well on Futon (sorry for the scroll)

```
function(doc) {
if (doc.ismaster != true && 
    (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=360) && 
    ((((doc.type=='field_order') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
     (((doc.type=='consumption_report') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
     (((doc.type=='production_order') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))<=10))) ||
     (((doc.type=='work_report') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=40))) ||
     (((doc.type=='pallet') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
     (((doc.type=='shipment') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) || 
     (((doc.type=='sowing_report') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))))){  
    emit([doc.type], doc);
}
```

}

And this is the replication filter that does not work with the same code:

```
 "filters": {
     "666": "function(doc, req) {
     if (doc.ismaster != true &&
         (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=360) &&
         ((((doc.type=='field_order') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
          (((doc.type=='consumption_report') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
          (((doc.type=='production_order') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))<=10))) ||
          (((doc.type=='work_report') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=40))) ||
          (((doc.type=='pallet') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
          (((doc.type=='shipment') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))) ||
          (((doc.type=='sowing_report') && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <=10))))) 
     return true;}",
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using couchbase sync gateway ?

Comment: sorry but I am not using CouchBase, I am using couchDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couchbase Lite doesn't currently support CouchDB filters.  It's a complex issue.  For more information, see [this documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html#filtered-pull-from-couchdb-pouchdb-or-cloudant) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/1139).

Comment: thanks @Hod are you  thinking about solve the filters support in future versions of couchbase lite; 1.5 maybe?